# Importing Unirest, dependencies issues

Tags: java, android, maven, unirest

So I was trying to import [Unirest for java](http://unirest.io/java.html) to make simple http requests.
Now I ran into warnings about duplicated dependencies regarding Apache dependencies. I first thought to solve this by adding this to the build.grandle:

```
packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
}
```

That did make it run, but still made it crash once I used any of the Unirest features.
So back to google came to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26771975/problems-using-unirest-in-android-studio). The [one and only answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29051117/2901207) pointed to [this tutorial](http://blog.mashape.com/using-unirest-java-for-your-android-projects/) which I decided to follow. So I downloaded mvn. First had some trouble with the JAVA_HOME, but set that correctly. then I did like he did: execute `mvn clean assembly:assembly`in the master folder of the github dir after editing the pom.xml

However, for me, it didn't generate the .jar files like he has.

What am I doing wrong? Could one please create it for me :)?

I do get a `target` folder like it should, in `cmd` it is downloading a bunch of files, but no .jar file.

In the Target folder I have 4 subfolders: classes, maven-status, surefire-reports, test-classes.

Some stack traces:in cmd

```
Failed tests:   testPostRawBody(com.mashape.unirest.test.http.UnirestTest): expe
cted:<'"@[?????]-test-123-0.01090655...> but was:<'"@[?????]-test-123-0.01090655
...>

Tests run: 36, Failures: 1, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 22.502 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2015-05-17T21:46:52+02:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 21M/178M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.
12.4:test (default-test) on project unirest-java: There are test failures.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] Please refer to C:\Users\Ruud\Downloads\unirest-java-master\unirest-java
-master\target\surefire-reports for the individual test results.
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e swit
ch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please rea
d the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureExc
eption
```

And then in the file it is referring to:

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Test set: com.mashape.unirest.test.http.UnirestTest
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Tests run: 36, Failures: 1, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 17.855 sec <<< FAILURE!
testPostRawBody(com.mashape.unirest.test.http.UnirestTest)  Time elapsed: 0.122 sec  <<< FAILURE!
org.junit.ComparisonFailure: expected:<'"@[?????]-test-123-0.01090655...> but was:<'"@[?????]-test-123-0.01090655...>
    at org.junit.Assert.assertEquals(Assert.java:115)
    at org.junit.Assert.assertEquals(Assert.java:144)
    at com.mashape.unirest.test.http.UnirestTest.testPostRawBody(UnirestTest.java:151)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.execute(JUnit4Provider.java:252)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:141)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:112)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethodWithArray(ReflectionUtils.java:189)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory$ProviderProxy.invoke(ProviderFactory.java:165)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory.invokeProvider(ProviderFactory.java:85)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:115)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:75)
```

Running on windows.

Answer (score 0):

I was having same issues with this while trying to build jar file with dependencies. Try running the modified mvn command but skip the tests

mvn clean assembly:assembly -Dmaven.test.skip=true

This worked for me. Also check out https://github.com/Mashape/unirest-java/issues/52