# Unirest with java - Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'

Tags: java, android, apache, unirest

I try to use unirest in my project at Android Studio.

They write in thier website:

> Don't forget to also install the dependencies (org.json, httpclient
>   4.3.6, httpmime 4.3.6, httpasyncclient 4.0.2) in the classpath too.

I do not know which libs to add for this.

I try to add this:

```
compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpasyncclient:4.1.1'
compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:4.5.1'
compile 'com.hynnet:httpclient:4.5.1'
```

And I get this exception:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.> 
com.android.build.transform.api.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: com/google/gson/annotations/Expose.class
```

Any help?

Comment: You should check: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26771975/problems-using-unirest-in-android-studio

Answer (score 0):

Try to Download the exact versions of the dependencies.

You can download from [here](https://archive.apache.org/dist/httpcomponents/httpclient/binary/httpcomponents-client-4.3.6-bin.zip) and [here](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/httpcomponents/httpasyncclient/4.0.2/httpasyncclient-4.0.2.jar)

If the problem persists. Tell me.